# error correction in declaration of a struct array

Tags: visual-c++

Please how can I correct this instruction in c++

```
const struct { unsigned int xIdx, yIdx, zIdx; } faceIndex[] { {0,1,2}, {2,0,1}, {1,2,0} };
```

thank you very much

Comment: what is the problem you're having with it? what do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an equal sign, as in:

```
const struct { unsigned int xIdx, yIdx, zIdx; }
    faceIndex[] = { {0,1,2}, {2,0,1}, {1,2,0} };
```

Comment: I used it and I don't have the error yet .I work with visual studio c++ version 6

Comment: Yes but not in this instruction but in

Comment: Well, if you have other errors, you could post other questions (after some personal research, mind you) or update this question. Anyway, don't forget to accept my answer if it answered your initial question.